# Generic method to retrieve an entity by Id with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I create an API in which I have several objects in the database (e.g. seller, product, etc.) and for each of these objects I provide an enpoint api to get a given object from the database using its Id (always of the Guid type). I noticed that in each class where I handle business logic, I repeat the same code:

```
//GetOneSellerQueryHandler class
...
var sellerDbItem = await Context.Seller.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
var seller = Mapper.Map<SellerDto>(sellerDbItem );
...

//GetOneProductQueryHandler class
...
var productDbItem = await Context.Product.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
var product = Mapper.Map<ProductDto>(productDbItem);
...
```

Does it make sense create abstract class with generic method to get element from db by passed id?

Moreover, is this implementation of the generic method correct?

```
//Abstract class
public async Task<F> GetElementById<T,F>(T obj, Guid id) where T : class
{
   T dbItem = (T) Convert.ChangeType(obj switch
   {
      Seller => await Context.Seller.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleAsync(),
      Product=> await Context.Product.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleAsync(),
      _=>throw new NotImplementedException()
   }, typeof(T));

   return Mapper.Map<F>(dbItem);
}


//GetOneProductQueryHandler class
...
var productDbItem = await GetElementById<Product, ProductDto>(new Product(), request.Id)
...
//GetOneSellerQueryHandler class
...
var sellerDbItem = await GetElementById<Seller, SellerDto>(new Seller(), request.Id)
...
```

Comment: EF Core or old EF6?

Comment: I use EF Core (version 6.x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it make sense create abstract class with generic method to get element from db by passed id?

My advice : Don't be afraid to repeat yourself.

Generic reduce the line count... but it can hurt the maintainability.

> Moreover, is this implementation of the generic method correct?

Not totally, because types are hard coded. Moreover the code that filter `Context.XXX.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleAsync()` is duplicated. This combine all defaults, more line and less maintainable.

EF Core use `Queryable`, then you can generate a generic expression like :

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static Task<T>? GetById<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Guid id)
    {
        // This expression is lambad : e => e.Id == id
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var left = Expression.Property(parameter, "Id");
        var right = Expression.Constant(id);
        var equal = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        var byId = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, parameter);
        
        return query.SingleAsync(byId);
    }
}

//Use
var seller = await context.Sellers.GetById(Guid.NewGuid());
var product = await context.Products.GetById(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Expression is powerful, but hard.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I declare base class/interface for database entities to access shared properties and create generic method based on them

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public interface IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Seller : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext ctx;

    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public Task<T> GetById<T>(Guid id) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return ctx.Set<T>().SingleAsync<T>(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

public class Handler<Entity, Dto> where Entity : class, IEntity
{
    private readonly Repository repository;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public Handler(Repository repository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<Dto> GetDtoById(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = await repository.GetById<Entity>(id);

        var dto = mapper.Map<Dto>(entity);

        return dto;
    }
}
```